# runc run failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory

Tags: docker

Hi I am creating an image on docker and below are the commands on Dockerfile

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

When I run the command Docker build . it gives below response

```
[+] Building 2.0s (8/8) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 138B                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:latest                                                                                                                                             1.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 295B                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s 
 => [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/node@sha256:eee19816ad7ae65dbcac037629c355fa4b369d163a660bc9718df8f945e79eeb                                                                                              0.0s 
 => CACHED [2/4] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s 
 => CACHED [3/4] COPY . /app                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s 
 => ERROR [4/4] RUN npm install                                                                                                                                                                            0.7s
------
** > [4/4] RUN npm install:
#8 0.673 runc run failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory**
```

Can some please guide

I was expecting the image to be built.

Comment: I suspect that the issue is with package.json file. Docker can not find it.

Comment: Could you show us the folder architecture? (like where is the dockerfile, the package.json, ...)

Comment: You also might double-check that you haven't overwritten the `node` image locally; try manually running `docker pull node` and then rebuilding.  I've seen this happen in Compose setups that `build:` a custom image but also incorrectly include `image:` naming the base image, which causes the base image to locally be overwritten.

Comment: Folder structure is below

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         10/7/2020  12:09 PM                public
-a----         10/7/2020  12:10 PM           6148 .DS_Store
-a----         1/11/2023   6:26 PM            101 Dockerfile
-a----         10/7/2020  12:09 PM            255 package.json
-a----         10/7/2020  12:09 PM            939 server.js

Comment: Docker just updated to `Docker version 23.0.0, build e92dd87` for me and nothing is building now. Running any command is giving me `runc run failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory`. I suspect its something with the update.

Comment: I had the same issue, uninstall by following instructions at https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#uninstall-docker-engine (with removal of existing images, containers, and volumes) solved issue on Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem in a CI/CD context and it was related to the `/var/lib/docker` directory.

So you can try these steps (doing so you will temporary loose all your Docker layers and images in your host but can revert the operation if not ok)

- Stop your docker service
- `sudo mv /var/lib/docker /var/lib/_docker`
- restart the Docker service (if needed, `sudo mkdir /var/lib/docker`)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error while trying to build an image for a python program and was able to resolve it by uninstalling the base image for me it was `python:3.8-alpine` with command `sudo docker rmi the_image_id`.

> `sudo docker images` should show the available images and their props from which you can get the image id to add to above script

```
you can as well try to use some other base image version/tags 
and see if the command runs fine -- this was my first attempt
while debugging
```

On subsequent build attempt, the command ran successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the problem was the base image I was using.
Once I changed it the error disappeared.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).